# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: m: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.studentdatabase.Student

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
public void onStart() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            studentArrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
               /** getValue error in this line  **/
               Student student =dataSnapshot1.getValue(Student.class);



               studentArrayList.add(student);

            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how `databaseReference` is initialized, and a snippet of the JSON at that path in the database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please provide the info  Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: you edit your question to show how databaseReference is initialized,